# CakePHP cake saveall not saving relation models

Tags: cakephp, orm, model, relation, cakephp-2.x

I'm trying to make an object which has all the fields needed to save a `Product`, its `n` variants and its `n` images. But for some reason the `saveAll()` is not working.

I tried saving an array of products with its variants and images, but no luck. It saved only the products as well. I do have the relations set up in the models

**`Product.php`**:

```
 public $hasMany = array(
    'product_variant' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductVariant',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'product_image' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductImage',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    ),
    'product_mercadolibre' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductMercadolibre',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false,
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
        'limit' => '',
        'offset' => '',
        'exclusive' => '',
        'finderQuery' => '',
        'counterQuery' => ''
    )
);
```

**`ProductVariant.php`**:

```
//The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
* belongsTo associations
*
* @var array
*/
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

and **`ProductImage.php`**:

```
/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Product' => array(
            'className' => 'Product',
            'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
```

Here is the Porduct object:

```
[Product] => Array
(
    [product_group_id] => 418112473
    [handle] => advocate-ct-circa
    [title] => Advocate CT Circa
    [body] => :html_body:
    [vendor] => Britax
    [type] => Car Seats
    [tags] => 0-3m, 12-18m, 18-24m, 24+m, 3-6m, 6-12m, auto asientos, britax, car seats, Dic152015, GooglePLA, hotsale-equipo, Niña, Niño, rn-18, Unisex
    [published_at] => 2015-06-24T01:02:00-05:00
    [published_scope] => global
    [option1_name] => Title
    [option1_value] => Default Title,
    [image_src] => https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/circa.jpg?v=1447768099
    [ProductVariant] => Array
        (
            [variant_id] => 1096438833
            [title] => Default Title
            [option1_name] => Default Title
            [option2_name] => 
            [option3_name] => 
            [variant_sku] => E9LT95Q - E1A265Q
            [variant_grams] => 0
            [variant_inventory_tracker] => shopify
            [variant_inventory_qty] => 4
            [variant_inventory_policy] => deny
            [variant_fulfillment_service] => manual
            [variant_price] => 8999.00
            [variant_compare_at_price] => 
            [variant_requires_shipping] => 1
            [variant_taxable] => 
            [variant_barcode] => 
            [variant_image] => 1151565069
            [variant_weight_unit] => kg
        )

    [PorductImage] => Array
        (
            [variant_image_id] => 1225124
            [variant_image] => https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/2780-ca4_2d26fff2-368d-4271-bd13-c344b5d08fb7.jpg?v=1447768100
        )

)
```

Here is the code I used to save the product object.

```
$this->Product->create();
if ($this->Product->saveAll($singleProduct)) {

} else {

    echo "Fallo guardar " . $singleProduct['handle'] . "<br>";

}
```

`$singleProduct` holds the object before mentioned.

All this saves only the `Product` model but not the variants or images. What am I doing wrong here? D:

**EDIT:**

I tried `saveAll()` with an array of products like so:

```
[
  {
    "Product": {
      "product_group_id": 418112473,
      "handle": "advocate-ct-circa",
      "title": "Advocate CT Circa",
      "body": "HTML-Body",
      "vendor": "Britax",
      "type": "Car Seats",
      "tags": "0-3m, 12-18m, 18-24m, 24+m, 3-6m, 6-12m, auto asientos, britax, car seats, Dic152015, GooglePLA, hotsale-equipo, Niña, Niño, rn-18, Unisex",
      "published_at": "2015-06-24T01:02:00-05:00",
      "published_scope": "global",
      "option1_name": "Title",
      "option1_value": "Default Title,",
      "image_src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/circa.jpg?v=1447768099"
    },
    "ProductVariant": [
      {
        "variant_id": 1096438833,
        "title": "Default Title",
        "option1_name": "Default Title",
        "option2_name": null,
        "option3_name": null,
        "variant_sku": "E9LT95Q - E1A265Q",
        "variant_grams": 0,
        "variant_inventory_tracker": "shopify",
        "variant_inventory_qty": 4,
        "variant_inventory_policy": "deny",
        "variant_fulfillment_service": "manual",
        "variant_price": "8999.00",
        "variant_compare_at_price": null,
        "variant_requires_shipping": true,
        "variant_taxable": false,
        "variant_barcode": "",
        "variant_image": 1151565069,
        "variant_weight_unit": "kg"
      }
    ],
    "ProductImage": [
      {
        "variant_image_id": 1151565069,
        "variant_image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/circa.jpg?v=1447768099"
      },
      .....
    ]
  },
  {
    "Product": {
      "product_group_id": 418498017,
      "handle": "advocate-ct-tahoe",
      "title": "Advocate CT Tahoe",
      "body": "HTML_BOdY",
      "vendor": "Britax",
      "type": "Car Seats",
      "tags": "0-3m, 12-18m, 18-24m, 24+m, 3-6m, 6-12m, auto asientos, britax, car seats, Dic152015, GooglePLA, hotsale-equipo, Niña, Niño, rn-18, Unisex",
      "published_at": "2015-06-24T01:02:00-05:00",
      "published_scope": "global",
      "option1_name": "Title",
      "option1_value": "Default Title,",
      "image_src": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/tahoe.jpg?v=1447768138"
    },
    "ProductVariant": [
      {
        "variant_id": 1097451593,
        "title": "Default Title",
        "option1_name": "Default Title",
        "option2_name": null,
        "option3_name": null,
        "variant_sku": "E1A265N",
        "variant_grams": 0,
        "variant_inventory_tracker": "shopify",
        "variant_inventory_qty": 2,
        "variant_inventory_policy": "deny",
        "variant_fulfillment_service": "manual",
        "variant_price": "8999.00",
        "variant_compare_at_price": null,
        "variant_requires_shipping": true,
        "variant_taxable": false,
        "variant_barcode": "",
        "variant_image": null,
        "variant_weight_unit": "kg"
      }
    ],
    "ProductImage": [
      {
        "variant_image_id": 1152463301,
        "variant_image": "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/tahoe.jpg?v=1447768138"
      },
      .......
    ]
  }
]
```

And Im back to square one D: It only saves the product images. Ive checked the models are corrected now. But it wont save the variants or the images.

Any thoughts on this? o.o

Comment: i think for example  ProductVariant should be associated array of this format 'ProductVariant'=>array(array( 'variant_id' =>1096438833))

Comment: Thanks @NNem for the advice, like below I tried this out but with no luck. The Product object is the only one being saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is not structured properly. To be able to save `hasMany` data, you have to feed the following to `saveAll()`:

```
[Product] => Array
(
    [product_group_id] => 418112473
    [handle] => advocate-ct-circa
    [title] => Advocate CT Circa
    [body] => :html_body:
    [vendor] => Britax
    [type] => Car Seats
    [tags] => 0-3m, 12-18m, 18-24m, 24+m, 3-6m, 6-12m, auto asientos, britax, car seats, Dic152015, GooglePLA, hotsale-equipo, Niña, Niño, rn-18, Unisex
    [published_at] => 2015-06-24T01:02:00-05:00
    [published_scope] => global
    [option1_name] => Title
    [option1_value] => Default Title,
    [image_src] => https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/circa.jpg?v=1447768099
)
[ProductVariant] => Array
( 
    Array 
    (
        [variant_id] => 1096438833
        [title] => Default Title
        [option1_name] => Default Title
        [option2_name] =>
        [option3_name] =>
        [variant_sku] => E9LT95Q - E1A265Q
        [variant_grams] => 0
        [variant_inventory_tracker] => shopify
        [variant_inventory_qty] => 4
        [variant_inventory_policy] => deny
        [variant_fulfillment_service] => manual
        [variant_price] => 8999.00
        [variant_compare_at_price] =>
        [variant_requires_shipping] => 1
        [variant_taxable] =>
        [variant_barcode] =>
        [variant_image] => 1151565069
        [variant_weight_unit] => kg
    )
)
[ProductImage] => Array
(
    Array 
    (
        [variant_image_id] => 1225124
        [variant_image] => https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0154/0015/products/2780-ca4_2d26fff2-368d-4271-bd13-c344b5d08fb7.jpg?v=1447768100
    )
)
```

**EDIT: Fix Relationships**

Replace your `Product` relationships with the following:

**`Product.php`**:

```
 public $hasMany = array(
    'ProductVariant' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductVariant',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ),
    'ProductImage' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductImage',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false
    ),
    'ProductMercadolibre' => array(
        'className' => 'ProductMercadolibre',
        'foreignKey' => 'product_id',
        'dependent' => false
    )
);
```

See

- [`Model::saveAssociated()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) in Cookbook 2.x | Saving your Data

Comment: Hi thanks for the response and the good advice. I read the saveAssociated and saveAll sections and modeled the object after the example but with no luck. Im not receiving any error, its just saving the Product object and ignoring the other two objects.

Comment: @JurgenFeuchter Did you try changing the array structure to match the one in this answer?

Comment: I've just realized the aliases used in the relationships don't match those used in `$singleProduct`. See my edit.

Comment: We got a winner! :D Thanks @InigoFlores for your help! :D I thought the className was the one that mattered :P hehehe Sometimes the answers are right under our nose D: hehehe Thanks again :D

Comment: Hey @InigoFlores quick question, if I was to make an array of Products, each with its variants and images. Would saveAll() work to save the product and its variants and images? Right now I tried that, but I got back to square one. Its only saving the product but not its associated models. Any ideas why this could be happening ?

Comment: You should be able to save the array by setting `'deep'=>true` on `saveAll()` or `saveMany()`. See  the examples in [`Model:saveMany()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-savemany-array-data-null-array-options-array)

Comment: Excelent! :D jajajaja it was ´saveMany()´ not save all, I also used the ´'deep'=>true´ option and it worked! :D Many thanks again you're a life saver :P hehehe

Comment: :) However, according to the docs, `saveAll()` should also work, as it's a wrapper for `saveMany()` and `saveAssociated()`.